# Count number of consecutive years in category array

Tags: categories, array

I need to count the number of consecutive years a user has been a member of our organization. For example, if they've been a member from in 2018, 2019, 2020 and 2021, their loyalty will be 4 years.

If they've been a member in 2018, 2019 and 2021, their loyalty will be 1 year (they missed 2020.)

I'm currently using Categories to assign a year to Users in Craft to do the assignment of a year to a person.

Hope that makes sense. I would very much appreciate some help on how to tackle it!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to build a custom plugin, this would be a good time to use Twig's [reduce](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/reduce.html) filter, which takes a set of values and iterates over them to output a single value based on supplied logic.

Using Andy's answer as the basis might look like this (untested):

```
{% set currentYear = now|date('Y') %}

{% set loyaltyScore = currentUser.years.all()|reduce(
    (score, year) => 
        score == 0 and year == currentYear or 
        score > 0 and year == currentYear - 1 ?
        score + 1,
        0
) %}
```

I'm assuming your data is already in the right order if it's a category group.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! So my categories are in the format of 2021/22, so I updated a bit to the following, but when I dd on `loyaltyScore` it's blank. I've not used reduce before so a bit unsure.

`{% set currentYear = now|date('Y') ~ '/' ~ now|date_modify("+1 year")|date('y') %}`

Comment: Trying to do maths on something that's not a number is going to be tricky! You should look to convert the format into a proper number with just a single year. You could convert "2021/22" to "2021" using Twig's slice filter: `{{ '2021/22'|slice(4) }}`

Comment: Thanks for your help - looks like this one is a bit beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

- Fetch all category values, push the year string to an array.
- Sort that array in descending order by value.
- Initialise a counter, loop over the array, cast each value as an integer:

  -- if first array value is same as the current year, increase a counter, otherwise break.

  -- if loop year equals previous loop year minus 1, increase a counter otherwise break.

Your loyalty value is the counter.

Comment: The code is the part I'm having trouble with 

Comment: That's fairly straightforward PHP, trying to do it in Twig is just making things more complicated (and really, you should minimise the amount of logic/processing in a Twig template). It would be worth looking at creating a Twig filter in a Craft module, which you could pass the user's years history to, e.g. `currentUser.years|myfilter`