# Count consecutive years in Tag array in a module

Tags: modules

I'm coming back to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37621/count-number-of-consecutive-years-in-category-array) after some time because I feel like I have a bit more knowledge to be able to tackle it. Starting from Andy's pseudo-code, this is what I've got and it seems to be working ok, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

I also wonder if I need to code a bit more defensively. I guess this runs on every request, so I'm not sure if it's something that could be optimized. The tags are added to the user after purchasing a membership through our Commerce store (in another module.)

Andy mentioned setting it up as a Twig filter but I haven't got to that point yet.

```
$user = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();

if (!$user) {
    return;
}

$loyalty = 0;
$currentYear = date('Y');
$previousYear = null;
$years = Tag::find()->groupId(1)->relatedTo($user)->all();
arsort($years);

foreach ($years as $year) {
    if ($year->title == $currentYear) {
        $loyalty++;
        $previousYear = bcsub($year->title, 1);
    }
    if (!empty($previousYear)) {
        if ($year->title == $previousYearMinusOne) {
            $loyalty++;
            $previousYear = bcsub($year->title, 1);
        }
    }
}
$user->setFieldValue('loyalty', $loyalty);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user);
```

I'd appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it some more, it seems to make sense to run it on `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` on user elements. Not 100% sure the rest of the code is great but it's working ok. Open to suggestions on how to improve!

```
Event::on(User::class, Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE, function (ModelEvent $event) {
    $user = $event->sender;
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $years = Tag::find()->groupId(1)->relatedTo($user)->all();
    arsort($years);
    $loyalty = 0;
    $previousYear = null;
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        if ($year->title == $currentYear) {
            $loyalty++;
            $previousYear = bcsub($year->title, 1);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($previousYear)) {
        if ($year->title == $previousYear) {
            $loyalty++;
            $previousYear = bcsub($year->title, 1);
        }
    }
    $user->setFieldValue('loyalty', $loyalty);
});
```